# Jpanel not showing when clicking run in netbeans

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i'm currently working on a java desktop project , oddly enough whenever i hit the run button , the Jpanel doesn't show up. I declared this as main but still it doesn't works. Any ideas ?

Here is the code for my Jpanel form.

Thanks in advance!.

```
package consumidor;


public class ventana extends javax.swing.JPanel {


     public ventana() {
        initComponents();
    }

     public static void main(String args[]) {

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new ventana().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jInternalFrame1 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        buscarProductoTxt = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        btnBuscarProducto = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        buscarProductoArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        jInternalFrame1.setVisible(true);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame1.getContentPane());
        jInternalFrame1.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame1Layout);
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jInternalFrame1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jInternalFrame1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Buscar producto por rut");

        jLabel2.setText("Ingresar rut del proveedor");

        buscarProductoTxt.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                buscarProductoTxtActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btnBuscarProducto.setText("Consultar");
        btnBuscarProducto.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnBuscarProductoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        buscarProductoArea.setColumns(20);
        buscarProductoArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(buscarProductoArea);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(buscarProductoTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 65, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btnBuscarProducto))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap(24, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(buscarProductoTxt, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(btnBuscarProducto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 20, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel2Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel2);
        jPanel2.setLayout(jPanel2Layout);
        jPanel2Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel2Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel2Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel2Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(0, 56, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 324, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        




    private void buscarProductoTxtActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

    }                                                 

    private void btnBuscarProductoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  

        String producto=buscarProductoTxt.getText();
        buscarProductoRut(producto);
        buscarProductoArea.setText("Rut proveedor: "+mostrarRut()+", Descripcion"
                + ": "+mostrarDecripcion());





    }                                                 


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btnBuscarProducto;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea buscarProductoArea;
    private javax.swing.JTextField buscarProductoTxt;
    private javax.swing.JInternalFrame jInternalFrame1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   

    private static boolean buscarProductoRut(java.lang.String arg0) {
        webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service service = new webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service();
        webservice.ProcesoProductos port = service.getProcesoProductosPort();
        return port.buscarProductoRut(arg0);
    }

    private static String mostrarRut() {
        webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service service = new webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service();
        webservice.ProcesoProductos port = service.getProcesoProductosPort();
        return port.mostrarRut();
    }

    private static String mostrarDecripcion() {
        webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service service = new webservice.ProcesoProductos_Service();
        webservice.ProcesoProductos port = service.getProcesoProductosPort();
        return port.mostrarDecripcion();
    }        
}
```

Comment: A component needs a window to be displayed - you should start with [How to Make Frames (Main Windows)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/frame.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing "odd" about this. Your ventana class is a JPanel, and yes, you create it and set it visible, but a JPanel by itself can not display, and to in fact have it show, it needs to be part of a visible "top-level window" such as a JFrame or JDialog. So if you want to show this JPanel in its own separate dialog window, put it into a JDialog, `pack()` the dialog, and then set the dialog visible. Or the quick and dirty way to do this is to put the ventana JPanel into a JOptionPane. e.g.,

```
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new ventana());
```

A JOptionPane will then create and display a *modal* JDialog that will display your ventana object.

Note that the ventana class name should begin with an upper-case letter, like all Java class names should.

Comment: You are 100% right , i don't know why i mixed Jpanel with Jframe. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Fernandoarenas: Read the tutorial link that MadProgrammer gave you to learn the gory details. Actually, you're better off creating JPanels since they're much more flexible than JFrames, as they can then be displayed in JFrames or JDialogs or other JPanels, .... wherever they are needed.